# What would be the correct preposition for the word "project" when speaking about members of a project

Tags: prepositions

What preposition would you use in this case:

> I am a coordinator for/at/in the company NorthAir?

I mean that I work as a coordinator there (e.g. I mean that it's my position within the company, not that I coordinate the company as such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At" and "for" are both common in describing a working position. "With" is also used in similar sentences.

I am a project coordinator at IBM.

I am a marketing manager with Intel.

I am a pilot for FedEx.

Prepositions are not always exact, and the reason for using specific ones in common phrases can be customary rather than strictly grammatical.

In general, "at" implies location, "for" implies service, and "with" implies association.